# how to add webpack plugin to react-rewired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I use rca with react-rewired wrapper. To add custom configuration to webpack I created `config-overrides.js` file where I store my config settings. I added an `babel-plugin-import` and it was pretty easy. But now I want to use `moment-locales-webpack-plugin` to configure only one locale in my app to cut off app's weight.

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addWebpackPlugin  } = require('customize-cra');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
  }),
  addWebpackPlugin(MomentLocalesPlugin, { localeToKeep: ['us'] }),
);
```

After `yarn start` it shows me:

Failed to compile.

```
MomentLocalesPlugin: received unknown options: _pluginCompat, hooks, name, parentCompilation, outputPath, outputFileSystem, inputFileSystem, recordsInputPath, recordsOutputPath, records, removedFiles, fileTimestamps, contextT
imestamps, resolverFactory, infrastructureLogger, resolvers, options, context, requestShortener, running, watchMode, _assetEmittingSourceCache, _assetEmittingWrittenFiles, watchFileSystem. Only `localesToKeep` and `ignoreInva
lidLocales` options are supported at the moment
```

Can you help me with that please?

**UPDATE**
I find out how to add a rule to `override` function, but still can't make it work with only 1 locale.

```
const { override, fixBabelImports } = require('customize-cra');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
  }),
  function(config) {
    const alias = config.resolve.alias || {};
    alias['@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$'] = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/icons.js');

    config.resolve.alias = alias;
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
      new MomentLocalesPlugin(),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ]);

    return config;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The right way to add a plugin to `customize-cra` according to [this issue](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/issues/58) is:

```js
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

const addMomentLocalesPlugin = config => {
  config.plugins.push(new MomentLocalesPlugin());
  return config;
}

module.exports = override(
  addMomentLocalesPlugin,
  //...
)
```

And if you want to keep only a few languages in your bundle, you can try:

```
new MomentLocalesPlugin({ localesToKeep: ['es-us', 'pt'] })
```

Instead of

```
new MomentLocalesPlugin()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error:

> Only `localesToKeep` and `ignoreInvalidLocales` options are supported at the moment

Try changing your code from `localeToKeep` to `localesToKeep`. With the s.

Comment: Do you mean you are still getting the error? Make sure you clear out and re-run yarn before trying again.

Comment: yes, i am still getting an error after re-run. Maybe I apply this plugin in a wrong way